# FullScreenMode in Java

Tags: java

I've been following the book 'Developing games in Java' by David Brackeen and in chapter 2 he teaches how to use full screen mode. The problem i am having is that when i go to run his source code, all i get is a white screen. I've spent hours on this and i believe it has something to do with Windows 7.

Thanks for your time!

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
The SimpleScreenManager class manages initializing and
displaying full screen graphics modes.
*/
public class SimpleScreenManager {

private GraphicsDevice device;

/**
    Creates a new SimpleScreenManager object.
*/
public SimpleScreenManager() {
    GraphicsEnvironment environment =
        GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    device = environment.getDefaultScreenDevice();

}


/**
    Enters full screen mode and changes the display mode.
*/
public void setFullScreen(DisplayMode displayMode,
    JFrame window)
{
    window.setUndecorated(true);
    window.setResizable(false);

    device.setFullScreenWindow(window);

    if (displayMode != null &&
        device.isDisplayChangeSupported())
    {
        try {
            device.setDisplayMode(displayMode);
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            // ignore - illegal mode for this device
        }
    }
}


/**
    Returns the window currently used in full screen mode.
*/
public Window getFullScreenWindow() {
    return device.getFullScreenWindow();
}


/**
    Restores the screen's display mode.
*/
public void restoreScreen() {
    Window window = device.getFullScreenWindow();
    if (window != null) {
        window.dispose();
    }
    device.setFullScreenWindow(null);
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    SimpleScreenManager t = new SimpleScreenManager();
    try {

        t.setFullScreen(new DisplayMode(1920, 1080, 64, 0), new JFrame());
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
     catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
    finally {
        t.restoreScreen();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Unless your life depend on that, you might want to avoid shouting 'help ASAP` on people who owe you nothing.

Comment: Try google. You might get other working solutions.

Comment: this code is outdated, don't use Thread.sleep(int) in the EventDispashThread,

Answer (score 0):

Toggle! toggle...

```
private void toggleDecoration(boolean decorated) {
    dispose();
    if (decorated) {
        //save last bounds and its extended state
        lastState = getExtendedState();
        lastBounds = getBounds();
        try{
            setExtendedState(getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        }
        catch(Exception ev){
            setBounds(getGraphicsConfiguration().getDevice().getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds());
            ev.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {
        //restore last bounds and its extended state
        setBounds(lastBounds);
        setExtendedState(lastState);
    }
    setUndecorated(decorated);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Now i have a noob question. Where and how do i use this? Thanks.

Comment: You have to edit to make it works in your Swing app... the basic idea is `dispose()` then `setUndecorated(currentdecoratedState)` then `setVisible(true)`...this will make a windows toggle full-screen or not...the rest in the code is to save/load the last extended state of a window